# I want to pass a valuelist to my SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I need to pass a list to my SQL Server stored procedure. I have generated the list and it is a comma delimited list of numbers using:

```
<cfquery name="House" datasource="#application.datasource#">
    SELECT cGLsubaccount
    FROM   HOUSE
    WHERE Right(cGLsubaccount,3) IN 
         (
           <cfloop index="i" list="#consulsub#">
              <cfoutput>#right(Trim(i) , 3)#,</cfoutput>
           </cfloop>
           00000000
         )
</cfquery>

<cfset GLsubacct = Valuelist(House.cGLsubaccount,",")>
```

Now, I pass it into the stored procedure using `cfprocparam` with cfsqltype to varchar(1000). (I read on google that this is the way to pass a list to the stored procedure).

```
<cfprocparam type="IN" value="#GLsubacct#" DBVARNAME="@GLsubacct" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

In the stored procedure, I did this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [rw].[sp_EFT_NoticeXLS2] (
      @Scope varchar(50)
      , @AcctPeriod char(6)
      , @CompanyID nchar(10)
      , @GLsubacct varchar(1000) = NULL
) 
AS......
```

and the SQL statement in the stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE #Houses (
   iHouse_ID        int,
   cName            varchar(50),
   cNumber          varchar(10),
   cPhoneNumber1    varchar(25),
   cAddressLine1    varchar(50),
   cCity            varchar(30),
   cStateCode       varchar(2),
   cZipCode     varchar(10),
   iUnitsAvailable  int,
   iRegOpsNumber    int,
   cOpsName     varchar(50),
   iRegionID        int,
   cRegionName      varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Houses (
   iHouse_ID, 
   cName, 
   cNumber,
   cPhoneNumber1,
   cAddressLine1, 
   cCity, 
   CStateCode, 
   cZipCode,
   iUnitsAvailable, 
   iRegOpsNumber, 
   cOpsName, 
   iRegionID, 
   cRegionName )
SELECT
   h2.iHouse_ID,
   h.cName, 
   h.cNumber, 
   h.cPhoneNumber1,
   h.cAddressLine1, 
   h.cCity, 
   h.CStateCode, 
   h.cZipCode, 
   h.iUnitsAvailable, 
   r.RegOpsNumber,
   r.opsname, 
   r.iRegion_ID, 
   r.regionname
FROM rw.fn_GetScopeHouses (@Scope, @dtReport, NULL, NULL, 0) h2 
        JOIN House h on h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
           AND h.cCompanyID = @CompanyID
           AND ( @GLsubacct IS NULL OR h.iHouse_ID IN ('+ @GLsubacct +') )
JOIN    rw.vw_Reg_Ops r on r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error. The error message is...

```
Error Executing Database Query.  
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '+ @GLsubacct +' to data type int.  

The error occurred in E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\TIPS4\Admin\EFTprocesspullfile.cfm: line 46

44 :         <cfprocparam type="IN" value="#CompanyID#" DBVARNAME="@CompanyID" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"><!--- TPecku added variable to be passed to the stored Proc --->
45 :         <cfif CompanyID EQ 0000>
46 :         <cfprocparam type="IN" value="#GLsubacct#" DBVARNAME="@GLsubacct" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
47 :         </cfif>
48 :    </cfstoredproc>
```

The error is in the stored procedure because that is where I have '+ @GLsubacct +'.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? (Sorry for the long post, I wanted to put as much detail as possible so you can understand what I'm doing.

Comment: Check out Table Valued Paramenters (TVP) that's probably what you want to use instead of passing a string.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Comment: Thanks rjdevereux, I looked at your link but I am still confused on how to move forward.

Comment: Well, you have a few options. One is using a string parsing function. Here are a bunch of ways you could do that: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings. One is passing a table to the stored procedure. To do that, you create a type (as in the above link) then use that as a `READONLY` parameter for your procedure. Regardless of what option you choose, you'd want to change your procedure to join to the table (either the table of split values or the tvp you use).

Comment: Thank you ZLK. I will work on your suggestion today and report back tomorrow on my progress.

Comment: *One is using a string parsing function* Yep. That would definitely. You should also consider replacing your first query with something like this, because it in its current form it is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work with something close to your existing code, you'll have to create a query string (replacing your insert statement) in the stored procedure and execute it.

I've created some dummy/test variables to see how the query looks using the PRINT statement.  You can start with the line of code with "DECLARE @execQuery varchar(MAX)" to the end to replace your insert statement.

Logic like this should fill the temp table #Houses with the data that you can then use.

```
-- test variables
DECLARE @Scope varchar(50), @AcctPeriod char(6), @CompanyID nchar(10), @GLsubacct varchar(1000), @dtReport VARCHAR(20);
SET @Scope = 'scope';
SET @AcctPeriod = 'fall';
SET @CompanyID = N'coID';
SET @dtReport = 'dtRpt'
SET @GLsubacct = '123,234,345,456'

-- copy code below this line
DECLARE @execQuery varchar(MAX)

SET @execQuery = 'insert into #Houses (
iHouse_ID, 
cName, 
cNumber,
cPhoneNumber1,
cAddressLine1, 
cCity, 
CStateCode, 
cZipCode,
iUnitsAvailable, 
iRegOpsNumber, 
cOpsName, 
iRegionID, 
cRegionName
)
select  
h2.iHouse_ID,
h.cName, 
h.cNumber, 
h.cPhoneNumber1,
h.cAddressLine1, 
h.cCity, 
h.CStateCode, 
h.cZipCode, 
h.iUnitsAvailable, 
r.RegOpsNumber,
r.opsname, 
r.iRegion_ID, 
r.regionname
FROM    rw.fn_GetScopeHouses ('''+ @Scope +''', '''+ @dtReport +''', NULL, NULL, 0) h2  
JOIN    House h on  h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
AND h.cCompanyID = N'''+ @CompanyID +''''
IF (@GLsubacct IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @execQuery = @execQuery + ' AND ( h.iHouse_ID IN ('+ @GLsubacct +') )'
END
SET @execQuery = @execQuery + 'JOIN rw.vw_Reg_Ops r on r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID'

--PRINT @execQuery 

EXEC @execQuery
```

Comment: Do not use dynamic sql if possible. Aside from other issues, it is vulnerable to SQL injection. A udf/table driven approach with a JOIN would be better IMO.

Comment: Wouldn't the cfstoredproc call with cfprocparam tags work like cfqueryparam?

Comment: If it were a regular SQL statement, executed *without* EXEC yes. However, the above builds a literal sql string (without any bind variables) and passes it into EXEC. (Sort of the SQL equivalent of using PreserveSingleQuotes). So any malicious sql inside the @variables will be executed.  If you absolutely must use dynamic sql, use [sp_executeSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead of EXEC. Though it does not work in all cases (for example with IN clauses). In this case, a table driven approach is better IMO.

Comment: *use sp_executeSQL instead of EXEC* ... with the proper parameters of course. Otherwise, it is probably the same as using EXEC.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to make it work. After I passed the list to the stored procedure variable, I couldn't use the variable directly in my sql statement, it didn't work, so what I did was to iterate through the contents of the variable and store them in a temp table. I then used the content of the temp table in my SQL statement. If you look above, you will see what I was trying to do that didn't work. What I ended up doing was....

```
declare @oneNumber int
declare @POS int
if @GLsubacct <> ''
begin 
--Step through the comma delimted list of numbers and plug each one into a temp table
create table #HouseList (HouseID int)
select @POS = patindex('%,%',@GLsubacct) 
while @POS > 0
begin
select @oneNumber = cast(left(@GLsubacct,@POS - 1) as int)
insert into #HouseList (HouseID) values (@oneNumber)
select @GLsubacct = right(@GLsubacct,len(@GLsubacct) - @POS)
select @POS = patindex('%,%',@GLsubacct) 
end
--do the last one which doesn't have any comma
select @oneNumber = cast(@GLsubacct as int)
insert into #HouseList (HouseID) values (@oneNumber)
end

-- Create #House table
CREATE  TABLE #Houses (
iHouse_ID       int,
cName           varchar(50),
cNumber         varchar(10),
cPhoneNumber1   varchar(25),
cAddressLine1   varchar(50),
cCity           varchar(30),
cStateCode      varchar(2),
cZipCode        varchar(10),
iUnitsAvailable int,
iRegOpsNumber   int,
cOpsName        varchar(50),
iRegionID       int,
cRegionName     varchar(50))

insert  into    #Houses (
iHouse_ID, 
cName, 
cNumber,
cPhoneNumber1,
cAddressLine1, 
cCity, 
CStateCode, 
cZipCode,
iUnitsAvailable, 
iRegOpsNumber, 
cOpsName, 
iRegionID, 
cRegionName)
select  
h2.iHouse_ID,
h.cName, 
h.cNumber, 
h.cPhoneNumber1,
h.cAddressLine1, 
h.cCity, 
h.CStateCode, 
h.cZipCode, 
h.iUnitsAvailable, 
r.RegOpsNumber,
r.opsname, 
r.iRegion_ID, 
r.regionname
from    rw.fn_GetScopeHouses (@Scope, @dtReport, NULL, NULL, 0) h2  
JOIN    House h on  h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
AND h.cGLsubaccount IN (select Houseid from #HouseList)
JOIN    rw.vw_Reg_Ops r on r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID
```

It worked perfectly!

Comment: You should put the "split" logic into a table valued UDF. Then you can use it with any list, from any procedure - not just this one :) See [the link ZLK posted in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852635/i-want-to-pass-a-valuelist-to-my-sql-server-stored-procedure#comment68926713_40852635) for some examples.